# Trying to convert React functional component to class component fails

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a `canvas` with **React** following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258), but I don't like to use functional components when they have state or lifecycle management (I feel that is what classes are for), so I am trying to translate the tutorial functional component into a class based one, and this is the code I came with:

```
import React from 'react';

class AppCanvas extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    this.canvas = null;
    this.context = null;
  }

  draw = ctx => {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff66'
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(50, 100, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI)
    ctx.fill()
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.context.canvas.width, this.context.canvas.height);
  }

  render () {
    this.draw(this.context)

    return (
      <canvas className={this.props.classes.canvas} ref={this.canvasRef} />
    )
  }
}

export default AppCanvas;
```

But I get the following error with it:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot add property fillStyle, object is not extensible
AppCanvas.draw
src/AppCanvas.js:13
  10 | }
  11 | 
  12 | draw = ctx => {
> 13 |   ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff66'
     | ^  14 |   ctx.beginPath()
  15 |   ctx.arc(50, 100, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI)
  16 |   ctx.fill()
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

componentDidMount() gets called after render(), during initial render() this.context is null and only gets initalized inside componentDidMount().

After moving this.draw(this.context) inside componentDidMount, the code should look like this.

```
import React from 'react';


class AppCanvas extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    this.canvas = null;
    this.context = null;
  }

  draw = ctx => {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff66'
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(50, 100, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI)
    ctx.fill()
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.draw(this.context)
    this.context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.context.canvas.width, this.context.canvas.height);
    this.draw(this.context)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <canvas className={this.props.classes.canvas} ref={this.canvasRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

[App Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXxs5.jpg)